# how to fix unit testing error UNHANDLED_REJECTION

Tags: html, reactjs

its failing getting error

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

Comment: Can we have a little of context ? A little of code ? Maybe you should read this page : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Interesting how this question gets smaller and smaller with every edit, it used to have code, but that gor removed, then the question itself got cut short.